# pass value to firestore database

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

Data doesnt get pushed to my firestore and i dont know why and what im doing wrong *Created web app*
followed by documentation. Im stuck feeling *Brain dead*

My script from documentation

```
// Write data to  firestore

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'mykey',
  authDomain: 'myauthdomain',
  projectId: 'myprojectid'
});


var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("felanmalan").add({
    namn: "firstname surname",
    epost: "mail@gmail.com",
    tel: "myphonenumber",
    fast: "where i live",
    meddelanse: "whats wrong with appartment"
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})

</script>
```

When i press enter i was thinking data would be passed to my firestore but nothing still empty. I thought this was going to be easy but thats not the case. Ive done a few html forms via php to mysql before but this seems to be over my head. Can someone explain how i can make this work on extremly basic level.

My end goal will be to have a html form that sends data to firestore then use a Zapier function to mail out that last in comming data. Wont set up yet another smtpserver for this lol!

Comment: You seem to be using the v9 version of the SDK, which uses a quite different syntax. I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9

Comment: That was what i was following so im lost here.

Comment: If you started on the same page, you've been looking at the v8 tab. If you switch to the v9 code samples, you'll see it gets methods like this: `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
`.  If you're still struggling with those, I recommend looking at the migration guide or using the compat libraries, both explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: So the codes from modular V9 tab:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

Should be inserted right after <script> tag in combination with existing namespaced v8 tab links??
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

Do i understand this correct?

Comment: Still no access to either read and write data from Firestore cloud. Documentation step by step seem not to work what ever i am doing.